# launch Xcode project using AppleScript

Tags: xcode, applescript, xcode4.5

i am a  beginning to regard AppleScript. i try to open the xcode project using Xcode. i have succeed to open the folder which contain the xcode project but not yet, the launch of the project using Xcode.any help please ?!

```
tell application "Finder" to open folder "workpace" of folder "Documents" of folder "user1" of folder "Users" of disk "Macintosh HD"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get file objects from normal paths with `POSIX file`:

```
tell application "Finder"
    open POSIX file "/Users/username/Documents/workspace/workspace.xcodeproj"
end tell
```

This is slightly slower, but it works even if Finder is not responding:

```
do shell script "open ~/Documents/workspace/workspace.xcodeproj"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your going to want to do something like this...

```
tell application "Xcode"
    open file "path:to:my:file.xcodeproj"
end tell
```

Comment: If the project is already open, there's a few second delay for some reason. `activate` would also make Xcode frontmost.

Comment: The delay is no longer then however long it takes for xcode to regularly open the project (by double clicking).  You are right about activate, but doesn't open automatically call activate (ie make the window frontmost)?

Comment: If I run `tell app "Xcode" to open "file.xcodeproj"` twice, it takes about three seconds the second time, but `tell app "Finder" to open "file.xcodeproj"` doesn't. Finder's open command and /usr/bin/open do, but not the open commands of applications.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the heads up!  I'll leave my answer as is and let you keep the proper one.

Comment: I'm aware this is an old question but how would you go about opening a specific file in Xcode ? tell Xcode to open "file.swift" for example just errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
    tell application "Xcode"
        open file "Macintosh HD:Users:YourUserName:YourFolder:YourFolder:YourFileProject.xcodeproj"
    end tell
```